# Send Mail to Local Exchange Server using php

Tags: php, apache, exchange-server

Is it possible to send mail to an exchange server that is running locally on our network using php-apache that is also running in a localhost? If its possible, can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thank You Guys in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just to install a local MTA like blatmail (assuming you're on Windows; if you're on Linux you have sendmail or an equivalent already and mail() should just work).

That said, assuming your Exchange server will forward without authentication from the local network, set SMTP to the address or hostname of your Exchange server in .ini (or ini_set "SMTP" to that in the script itself).

Note that the vanilla mail() doesn't support authentication, and I'm pretty sure doesn't support TLS.
So you should definitely only use it on a completely trusted network.